# VoIP/SIP to make calls with background music

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sip, voip

I'm looking to create an app where two users can chat to each other while one of them plays music in the background. The music will be played from a file and will need to be mixed with the input from the microphone so that the other user can hear it too.

I've been looking at PJSIP which looks like it can do this but I was just wondering if there where any easy to implement alternatives that were more objective c and less plain c?

Answer (score 0):

PJSIP can do this.  A colleague of mine did it and followed

http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/page_pjsip_sample_simple_pjsuaua_c.htm

He had to convert the music to wav to lower the bitrate.

Hope that help.